# Webgrid and formatting DateTime value when grid columns are built in model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webgrid

I am creating a collection of WebGridColumns, adding them to my model and passing that to my razor page. I am doing this because there are a variable number of columns that are determined on the fly. 
This works well, but now I need to format datetime values to short date and am not sure how this can be accomplished when creating the collection of webgridcolumns.

```
 foreach (var datetimeitem in cols)
            {                    
                columns.Add(new WebGridColumn
                {   
                    ColumnName = datetimeitem,
                    Header = "MyHeader",
                    Format = **format item here**;

                });
            }
```

Any ideas?

J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your setup look something like this?

```
@{
    var cols = new[] { "FirstDate", "SecondDate" };
    var columns = new List<WebGridColumn>();

    var grid = new WebGrid(new[]
    {
        new Entity { FirstDate = DateTime.Now, SecondDate = DateTime.Now },
        new Entity { FirstDate = DateTime.MinValue, SecondDate = DateTime.MinValue }
    });
}
```

If so, you can try

```
@foreach (var datetimeitem in cols)
{                    
    columns.Add(new WebGridColumn
    {   
        ColumnName = datetimeitem,
        Header = "MyHeader",
        // If item is already a date time
        Format = m => m[datetimeitem].ToShortDateString()
        // If you need to parse item as date time first
        // Format = m => DateTime.Parse(m[datetimeitem]).ToShortDateString()
    });
}

@grid.GetHtml(columns: columns)
```

Comment: Is there something I'm missing? The "FormatDateTime" throws "a doesn't exist in current Context" message.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. what type of object are you using for a data source? A list of objects, or more like a data table? Can you give an example?

Comment: Using the results of a Linq query against EF Entities.

Comment: See if the above works for you, if not explain your set up differs

Comment: Actually the code you are showing above is almost exactly what I am doing but in my class file (with the exception of @grid.GetHtml(columns:columns) which is being done in Razor code as you have it.) I would prefer to keep the razor code to an absolute minimum.

Comment: Perfect, so assigning the `m => m[datetimeitem].ToShortDateString()` function to the `Format` property is all that was necessary?

Comment: Actually it does. All is working as expected. Now I just have to figure out how to deal with null dates. :) Always seems to be one more issue.
Thanks